# Stored MySQL Function to Count String Occurances

Tags: mysql, sql, function, count, user-defined-functions

not done many MySQL functions before… So, I am looking to have my function count the number of needles in the haystack below.  I keep getting:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7`

Which is the line with "RETURN," Here is what I have:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `str_count`(needle TEXT, haystack TEXT) 
RETURNS INT(5)
BEGIN

  RETURN (LENGTH(haystack) - LENGTH(REPLACE(haystack, needle, ""))) / LENGTH(needle);

END$$
```

Never done this kind of function before, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: works perfectly fine for me

Comment: Can you explain the problem with example

Comment: I would love the following to work: str_count("ab","abcdeabcabab") to return 4. Basically a MySQL version of http://us2.php.net/substr_count

Comment: By golly, you are right @tomborn! For some reason my MySQL interface was giving me trouble.  I will leave this post up though, because I have been unable to find somewhere that has this function anywhere online. Thanks again!

Comment: Use LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(haystack), LOWER(needle), "")) to replace case insesitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel silly.  When running this kind of stuff, make sure you define the Delimiter in the phpMyAdmin text box below the SQL textarea… In my case "$$" but it works great now!